# make a hash from active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash

It could be have similar names and dates. but, take sum of count of similar dates.

```
   #<ActiveRecord::Relation [Model name: "a", date: "20190703", count: 20>
   #<ActiveRecord::Relation [Model name: "b", date: "20190702", count: 10>
   #<ActiveRecord::Relation [Model name: "a", date: "20190702", count: nil>
   #<ActiveRecord::Relation [Model name: "c", date: "20190703", count: 20>
   #<ActiveRecord::Relation [Model name: "c", date: "20190702", count: 3>
   #<ActiveRecord::Relation [Model name: "c", date: "20190702", count: 5> ...etc
```

Expected result would be like

```
{
    :name=>"a", :data=>[{:date=>20190702, :count=>10}, {:date=>20190703, :count=>20}.....]
    :name=>"b", :data=>[{:date=>20190702, :count=>10}, ...etc]
    :name=>"c", :data=>[{:date=>20190702, :count=>8}, {:date=>20190703, :count=>20}, ..etc]
}
```

Comment: That is not a valid `Hash` please provide a valid syntax.

Comment: That array can't be "floating" inside the hash, must be assigned to a key.

Comment: sorry, i just updated final hash.

Comment: A better format for the hash would probably be using the name as the key: `{"a" => [{:date=>20190702, :count=>10}, {:date=>20190703, :count=>20}], "b" => [{:date=>20190702, :count=>10}]}`

If you wanted to, you could even use the date for the inner key, too, but it would depend how you want to use the data: `{"a" => {20190702 => 10, 20190703 => 20}, "b" => {20190702 => 10}}`

Comment: @DaveMongoose .. thank you. your first case (array inside hash) should be fine.

Comment: @GaneshRaju check provided answer and verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given the fact that this is ActiveRecord data to begin with why not something like

```
data = Model.group(:name,:date).order(name: :asc, date: :asc).sum(:count)
data.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) do |((name,date),count),obj|
  obj[name] << {date: date, count: count} 
end
```

This will produce:

```
{
  "a"=>[{:date=>20190702, :count=>0}, {:date=>20190703, :count=>20}],
  "b"=>[{:date=>20190702, :count=>10}],
  "c"=>[{:date=>20190702, :count=>8}, {:date=>20190703, :count=>20}]
}
```

and all of the summing and grouping is placed on the SQL side of things (which is very efficient at aggregation)

Comment: tq for ur answer. extend to that if any date was missing ( ex: expected output having 2nd and 4rd and third having no data) .. how to make hash with missing date with count will be zero

Comment: @GaneshRaju that is a new and different question please feel free to post as such

Comment: sure I will post as new question.

Comment: {"a" => {20190702 => 10, 20190703 => 20}, "b" => {20190702 => 10}} can we make in this format.

Comment: Thank you brother. I will try it.

Comment: `data.each_with_object(empty_hash) {|((site,date),count),hash| hash[site].store date, count }`

Answer (score 1):

You can have,

```
hash = users.group_by { |x| x.name }

hash.map do |name, model_data|
  {  
     name: name,
     data: model_data.group_by { |x| x[:date] }.values.map { |z| {date: z[0][:date], count: (z.inject(0) { |m,a| m += a[:count].to_i })} }
  }
end
```

Output will be,

```
[
    {:name=>"a", :data=>[{:date=>20190702, :count=>10}, {:date=>20190703, :count=>20}.....]},
    {:name=>"b", :data=>[{:date=>20190702, :count=>10}, ...etc]},
    {:name=>"c", :data=>[{:date=>20190702, :count=>8}, {:date=>20190703, :count=>20}, ..etc]}
]
```